# Iptables -C (--check) doesn't work

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall, linux-networking

I have the following Iptables version:

```
sh# iptables --version
iptables v1.4.21
```

The help page contains this line:

```
--check   -C chain      Check for the existence of a rule
```

I have such a rule in `iptables-save`:

```
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j CT --helper sip
```

But when I'm trying to check (`-C`) it I see such output:

```
sh# iptables -C PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j CT --helper sip
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
```

What is the reason? Could some bug be in Iptables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `-t nat` so you select the NAT table, or maybe `-t mangle`. Pretty sure it will default to looking at the filter table, which won't have a PREROUTING chain. You need to specify which table you are looking at.

```
sh# iptables -C PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -m udp --dport 5060 -j CT --helper sip
```

Comment: Actually for this one it's `-t raw` (the only one allowing the use of [`-j CT`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#CT))

Comment: Ah, good point. I wasn't paying attention to that.